# matlab gui code for browsing an image and converting image to grayscale

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

this is the code for matlab gui code for browsing an image and converting image to grayscale 
somebody please correct my code it's not working properly as i want,i tried alot but can't get it what's wrong in this

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.edit3, 'Visible','off');
% Build the complete filename
global im,im2
[filename, pathname]=uigetfile( {'*.jpg';'*.jpeg';'*.gif';'*.png';'*.bmp'},'Select file'); 
 MyImage = strcat(pathname, filename);

%This code checks if the user pressed cancel on the dialog.
        if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
            uiwait(msgbox ('User pressed cancel','failed','modal')  )
            hold on;
        else
            uiwait(msgbox('User selected image sucessfully','sucess','modal'));
            hold off;      

        end
        im=imread(path);
        im=im2double(im); %converts to double
         %for backup process :)
imshow(MyImage,'Parent',handles.axes2);
title('INPUT IMAGE WITH NOISE')
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);


% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a fusture version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata,handles,varargin)
global im
imblack=im;
rgb2gray(imblack);
imshow(imblack,'Parent',handles.axes2);
title(' IMAGE AFTER GRAYSCALE CONVERSION')
%gaussian filter:
  %set(handles.axes2, 'Visible','off');
  %set(handles.edit3, 'Visible','on');
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'UNTITLED_OutputFcn' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 265
        feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
 ??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2

Comment: Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
 ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2

Comment: Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in ==>

Comment: @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2

Comment: Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2

Comment: please help me to correct those errors i am sending u the image also

Comment: Please make an edit to your post rather than posting that to the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the updated code

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.edit3, 'Visible','off');
% Build the complete filename
global im
[filename, pathname]=uigetfile( {'*.jpg';'*.jpeg';'*.gif';'*.png';'*.bmp'},'Select file'); 
 MyImage = strcat(pathname, filename);

%This code checks if the user pressed cancel on the dialog.
        if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
            uiwait(msgbox ('User pressed cancel','failed','modal')  )
            hold on;
        else
            uiwait(msgbox('User selected image sucessfully','sucess','modal'));
            hold off;      

        end
        im=imread(MyImage);
        im=im2double(im); %converts to double
         %for backup process :)
imshow(im,'Parent',handles.axes2);
title('INPUT IMAGE WITH NOISE')
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);


% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a fusture version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata,handles,varargin)
global im
imblack=rgb2gray(im);
imshow(imblack,'Parent',handles.axes2);
title(' IMAGE AFTER GRAYSCALE CONVERSION')
%gaussian filter:
  %set(handles.axes2, 'Visible','off');
  %set(handles.edit3, 'Visible','on');
```

Changes made

1) `im=imread(path);` there is no variable in there with name `path`.

2) `imshow(MyImage,'Parent',handles.axes2);` `MyImage` contains file path. `im` contains the image.

3) `rgb2gray(imblack);` returned value must be stored in a variable to plot in next line.

4) `imshow(imblack,'Parent',handles.axes2);` if image is properly passed from previous button callback. Then input image will be shown instead of grey scale.

5) `global im,im2` `im2` not used so `im2` was removed

Comment: ??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'UNTITLED_OutputFcn' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 265
        feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);
Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Comment: ??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2 Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:}Error in==>@(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Error using ==> feval
Undefined function or method 'UNTITLED_OutputFcn' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 265
        feval(gui_State.gui_OutputFcn, gui_hFigure, [], gui_Handles);

Comment: Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:}); 
??? Undefined function or variable 'im2'.
Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81
global im,im2
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: errors while executing this your corrected code is not working

Comment: Error 2 from above : There is no `im2` in the above code. Then how can you have an error saying `Undefined function or variable 'im2'.` ?

Comment: I have changed `global im,im2` to `global im` and yet your error says `Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton1_Callback at 81 global im,im2`